# Is it possible to show in the products grid the length of time that the product has been out of stock

Tags: products, stock, status

I would like to be able to show in the product grid how long the item has been out of stock, is this possible?

I am presuming its only possible if there's a record of when the stock status was changed, which doesn't exist yet, but this sort of information can be recorded using an observer can't it?

What code can I use to achieve this?

Comment: Did you manage to get your issue resolved?

Answer (score 1):

You're correct in the information not being available out of the box. Magento just records the absolute stock qty, not the stock movement.

There are as far as I can see 2 options.

**Option 1: Writing your own stock movement module**

You could write a module that adds a table for this data, with fields like `product_id`, `date_updated`, `qty`.

Then using an observer on the `Mage_Cataloginventory_Model_Stock_Item` model save after event (`cataloginventory_stock_item_save_after`) storing this data. The observer would probably look something like below

```
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Observer
{
   public function trackStockMovement($observer)
   {
      $obj = $observer->getEvent()->getDataObject();
      $productId = $obj->getProduct()->getId();
      $qty = $obj->getQty();

      /**
       * here goes the code to save data
       */
   }
}
```

This would store all stock movement. Optionally you could save just when `qty` equals 0.

Next to that I would advice writing a cronjob in the module that cleans out stock movement older than X months to prevent massive database tables.

From that data you can retrieve the out of stock length for the frontend.

**Option 2: dude... too much data**

Or use a custom module that has an observer on product save (`catalog_product_save_before`) that stores the current date in a product attribute when stock qty equals 0. Something along this line:

```
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Observer
{
   public function trackStockMovement($observer)
   {
      $obj = $observer->getEvent()->getDataObject();
      $qty = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')
           ->loadByProduct($obj->getProduct());

      if ($qty == 0 && $obj->getData('out_of_stock_since') == null) {
         $obj->setData('out_of_stock_since', time());
      } else if ($qty>0) {
         $obj->setData('out_of_stock_since', null);
      }
   }
}
```

Make sure you create a product attribute `out_of_stock_since` add set it to be used in product listing. Then add it to your category list, product view or where ever you want to display it

*Disclaimer: Untested code so please do not use on live environment.*